# Will leaving corpses lying around upset my prisoners?

Tags: prison-architect

I see questions/information online about how to get rid of corpses but I'm not sure what the consequences to having them lying around are.

I know that I can use a morgue to store them and that they will eventually be taken away in a hearse. However, I've always just left them lying around. This doesn't seem to have any obvious consequences.

Do they upset prisoners or staff (e.g. increasing the danger level beyond what death normally does)? Make them sick? Slow down pathing? Is this something that's not implemented yet or is leaving dead bodies all over the place meant to be completely fine?

The wiki's pages for [Death](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Death) and [Morgue](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Morgue) don't shed any light on this. All I'm finding is the *how* of getting rid of corpses/glitches related to it but not *why* it matters in the first place. All I've seen that's related is that apparently prisoners can loot guard corpses for keys, but there's no obvious consequences for prisoner corpses which are what I tend to end up with.

So why not just leave them in the corridors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there's currently any effect on the mood or efficiency of your staff or prisoners.

However, there's still something to keep in mind: dead (and unconscious) characters can be looted. If a staff member dies, then prompt movement to a morgue can prevent prisoners from looting Staff Keys off the corpse. This is even more important when the corpse is a guard, since Jail Keys and weapons can be taken.

To a much less severe degree, storage of prisoner corpses in morgues will prevent access to any contraband they may have been carrying.

If you do build a morgue, you will have to ensure your morgue is properly protected to prevent prisoners from walking in and just taking the items from dead bodies.

Comment: This corroborates what I've noticed over the past couple days (e.g. if I do a shakedown right after a riot lots of prisoners will have jail keys, tazers, and even shotguns from dead guards) so I'm giving it a +1 for now. I realize this is a tricky question to answer since there may just be no evidence one way or the other, thus indicating "probably not" but meaning it's tough to give a good answer. This could end up being the best answer in which case I'll mark it as correct within the next couple days.

Answer (score 1):

There is no consequence for leaving corpses anywhere. All it does if leave a mark of failure in your path of making a fully functional prison.